# multi-master databases in low connectivity environments

Tags: networking, database

I'm working on a project that has many client devices distributed in remote environments where connectivity losses are frequent and expected. Clients continue to operate when offline, but when these devices are reachable, they receive commands from a set of servers in the cloud and communicate status to these same servers.

The client devices and the servers both maintain information on "account balance" and that information is mutable on both ends. That is, account balances can be changed by users of the cloud interface or the local client interface, and these changes can be made even when the client is offline.

It's my understanding that this is a "multi-master" database setup, in some sense. I'm wondering what projects exist to help manage this kind of topology. Are there any examples of similar projects out there? Or are there other architectures worth considering?

Answer (score 0):

Tungsten can be set up in an asynchronous multi-master architecture which is essentially what you are after, and can be used with various DBs: https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/

The application could be set up to use a local MySQL back end utilizing Tungsten and it would sync with the other servers whenever it was online. When offline the updates would queue until online again. The clients would want to be connected via VPN or similar (eg. HTTPS / SSH tunnel).